# How are the requests handled in GRPC?

Tags: go, grpc

Lets say that my given GRPC endpoint has the following implementation

```
type HandlerFunc func(ctx context.Context, in *pb.Request) (*pb.Response, error)

func newHandler() HandlerFunc {
   func (s *Server) Process(ctx context.Context, in *pb.Request) (*pb.Response, error) {
        //do processing
    }
}

type Server struct {
    Handler handler
}

func new() (s *Server) {
   return &Server{
      handler: handlers.newHandler()
   }
}
func (s *Server) Process(ctx context.Context, in *pb.Request) (*pb.Response, error) {
    return s.handler
}
```

Now lets say that multiple clients try to call the Process endpoint. Do all of them call the same Process function of the same instance of the server or they call the Process function of the different instance of the server?

Also the handler defined in

```
func newHandler() HandlerFunc {
   func (s *Server) Process(ctx context.Context, in *pb.Request) (*pb.Response, error) {
        //do processing
    }
}
```

Is the same instance of the handler handling multiple requests from the same client? Also how about different clients? Is the same instance of the handler handling requests from multiple clients?

Comment: What do you mean "different instances of the server"? Are you running multiple instances of the server? If you're only running one instance of the server, then they are handled by the same instance of the server. As for using the "same instance of the handler", that doesn't really make sense, since a handler only handles one request. Handlers are run concurrently for concurrent requests, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @JimB. Yes multiple requests. So for each request a new instance of the handler is created? What if I have to share stuff between multiple requests. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry but I'm having a hard time understanding the code you provided. Seems like `Process` is the RPC call that you're writing a service handler for. But what is the `handler` type then. Also the function `newHandler()` is used as a method. Moreover, I don't see the need of wrapping the service handler either.

How about we take the official [example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/examples/helloworld/) for unary RPCs from gRPC's github.

If you look [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/858463ac273fd87e6b2343eda6e96ed3a91e3b20/examples/helloworld/greeter_server/main.go#L38), a gRPC service handler is defined which handles `SayHello` RPC.

Multiple clients can make multiple calls to this RPC, all of which will be run in a separate goroutine. Now, it is understandable that one might want to share some information between these calls. This can be achieved by augmenting your service handler `type server struct` with more logic, for instance a data structure with a mutex.

Hopefully, this answers some questions.

Best
Mak